# Java program to find which string is replaced by which string?

Tags: string, replace

String s1="Welcome To Java";
String s2="Wela To Java";

Write a Java program to get the output that come is replaced by a.

Comment: Please help me with the program.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is no free coding service

Comment: String s1= "Welcome to Java";

 String s2= "Wela to java";

 String[] str1= s1.split("\\s");

 String[] str2= s2.split("\\s");
  
  for (int t1=0;t1<str1.length;t1++) {
   for (int t2=0;t1<str2.length;t2++){
    
    if(!str2[t2].equals(str1[t1]))
     System.out.println(str1[t2]+"---"+str1[t1]);
    break;
    
   }

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that that is one char replacing multi chars, you can use this:

```
String s1="Welcome To Java"; 
String s2="Wela To Java";
for (int i = 1; i < s2.length()+1; i++){
    char c = s2.charAt(i-1);
    String part1= s2.substring (0,i-1);
    String part2=s2.substring(i);
    if (s1.contains(part1)&&(s1.contains(part2))){
         int t1 = s1.lastIndexOf(part1)+part1.length();
         int t2 = s1.indexOf(part2);
         System.out.println("Found  "+s1.substring(t1,t2)+ " is replaced by "+c);                 
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gary.Y for your solution.
 But my doubt was: Compare the two string and figure out which string is replaced by what so that the output will come "come is replaced by a"

Comment: Edited but If you want more flexibility you need regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is replace all instances of the word 'come' with 'a', you should read up pattern-matching and the .replace() method in Java. See the docs for this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

The above works nicely for either a specific string or more general patterns in the data you're working with.

P.S. Your question is unlikely to get a good answer because it's a pretty straightforward thing that requires just a quick search. I can tell you now that asking on Stack Overflow as a last resort is a good policy to follow.